# Coordinatorlayout containing NestedScrollView containing ExpandableListView scroll issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-nestedscrollview

[image]I have a Coordinatorlayout containing NestedScrollView containing ExpandableListView scroll. It works fine till groups are collapsed but as soon as they expand it behaves weird. The NestedScrollView starts going behind the top view rather than giving it a parallax effect.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/frag_itemdetail_scrl_nested"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/frag_itemdetail_explist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:transcriptMode="disabled"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_194">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/frag_itemdetail_iv_itemimage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/instantt"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7">
                </ImageView>

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/frag_itemdetail_prg_itemimage"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the snippet and where is the screenshot ?

Comment: @PiyushGupta now have a look,

Comment: Change this _app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"_ for _CoordinateLayout_ and set   _app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"_ for _Toolbar_

Comment: Still same problem. Not working. As soon as the expandable child items are visible it starts going behind the above portion.
When I am scrolling it through the black portion it works fine,

Comment: Why applied weight to _CoordinateLayout_ ? Also use _android:fitsSystemWindows="true"_ for  _CoordinateLayout_

Comment: Weight 1 bcz I have an another layout at the bottom. Still not working. Its been 2 days since I am stuck in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117284/discussion-between-rishabh-srivastava-and-piyush-gupta).

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava facing the similar issue. Did you got any solution for this issue.

Comment: I used https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll